# Excel VBA - Autofit multiple charts & tables into word at bookmarks?

Tags: vba, excel

I am struggling to add Autofit to my sub when pasting multiple chats and tables into word at defined bookmarks. I have tried multiple methods, but my lack of experience is showing through and the sub either fails or does not autofit when I add/mess with autofits.

It runs fine as it stands below:

```
'To open a template word file '"C:\Users\USER\Documents\Custom Office  Templates\Test161231.dotm"
'To copy ranges and charts as referenced on this excel workbook sheet "Bookmarks"
'To paste ranges and charts at predefined bookmarks within the open word    template as referenced on this excel workbook sheet "Bookmarks"
'To save the open word template as a .Docx

Sub OpenPopulateSave()

Dim wApp As Word.Application
Dim wDoc As Word.Document
Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wApp.Visible = True
Dim x               As Long
Dim LastRow         As Long
Dim SheetChart      As String
Dim SheetRange      As String
Dim BookMarkChart   As String
Dim BookMarkRange   As String
Dim Prompt          As String
Dim Title           As String

'Turn some stuff off while the macro is running
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'Determine the last row of data for our loop
LastRow = Sheets("Bookmarks").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'Create an instance of Word for us to use
Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

'Open our specified Word file, On Error is used in case the file is not there
On Error Resume Next
Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Open("C:\Users\USER\Documents\Custom Office Templates\Test161231.dotm", ReadOnly:=True)
On Error GoTo 0

'If the file is not found, we need to end the sub and let the user know
If wDoc Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Unable to find the Word file.", vbCritical, "File Not Found"
    wApp.Quit
    Set wApp = Nothing
    Exit Sub
End If

'Copy/Paste Loop starts here
For x = 2 To 20

'Use the Status Bar to let the user know what the current progress is
Prompt = "Copying Data: " & x - 1 & " of " & LastRow - 1 & "   (" & _
    Format((x - 1) / (LastRow - 1), "Percent") & ")"
Application.StatusBar = Prompt

'Assign the worksheet names and bookmark names to a variable
'Use With to group these lines together
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Bookmarks")
    SheetChart = .Range("A" & x).Text
    SheetRange = .Range("B" & x).Text
    BookMarkChart = .Range("C" & x).Text
    BookMarkRange = .Range("D" & x).Text

End With

If Len(BookMarkRange) > 0 Then
'Tell Word to goto the bookmark assigned to the variable BookMarkRange
wApp.Selection.Goto What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:=BookMarkRange

'Copy the data from Thisworkbook
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetRange).UsedRange.Copy

'Paste into Word
wApp.Selection.Paste

'Autofit Table so it fits inside Word Document window
'?

End If

If Len(BookMarkChart) > 0 Then
'Tell Word to goto the bookmark assigned to the variable BookMarkChart
wApp.Selection.Goto What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:=BookMarkChart

   'Copy the data from Thisworkbook
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetChart).ChartObjects(1).Copy

'Paste into Word
wApp.Selection.Paste

'Autofit Chart so it fits inside Word Document window
'?

End If

Next

'Turn everything back on
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.StatusBar = False

'Let the user know the procedure is now complete
Prompt = "Your report has now been generated." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "You may now edit the word document."
Title = "Procedure Completion"
MsgBox Prompt, vbOKOnly + vbInformation, Title

'Make our Word session visible
wApp.Visible = True

With wDoc

.SaveAs ActiveWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "Test3_" & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm") & ".docx", FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument
wApp.DisplayAlerts = True

End With

'Clean up
Set wApp = Nothing
Set wDoc = Nothing

End Sub
```

Any help and other useful comments would be greatly appreciated! I'm still in the early learning phase.

Answer (score 0):

I could find the following right away:

1. You use `Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")` twice (during variable declaration and after `LastRow = Sheets("Bookmarks").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`)
2. When you Stop your code by `Exit Sub` please note that you turn 'some stuff' (ScreenUpdating, Alerts, Events) back on (see: `If wDoc Is Nothing Then`)
3. You start your Loop `For x = 2 To 20` but you never really loop (no `next x`)
4. I guess that you want to use the LastRow result during your Loop (`For x = 2 To LastRow`).
5. For the autofit try: `Dim WordTable As Word.Table`, `Set WordTable = myDoc.Tables(1)`, `WordTable.AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitWindow)`

Comment: Thanks Snibbo. Points taken. I amended point 1. With point 2., wouldn't  the 'stuff' only turn back on if the IF statement was true, which would not normally be the case?

Comment: Point 3. I will do some more research on loops. The code does seem to do everything I want (except autofit). I used some existing code, as I had not used loops before, so keen to learn more.

Comment: Point 4. I originally had 'To LastRow' in place of 'To 20', but in column 'A' I had only 4 items (Chart references), while in column 'B' I had 7 items (Table references), the loop would then stop at the 4th chart and the 4th table, leaving the remaining three tables out and the the last three bookmarks unpopulated.

Comment: Point 5. does not seem to work and was a method I tried at length previously. Thanks though.

Comment: Dear Hoplo, to (2): I do not think the Programm will automatically turn on the alters. Just try by giving a wrong path. 

To (4): If you not fill all columns of a row, you need to compare the various columns you used. `LastRow = Sheets("Bookmarks").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` checks for column "A". If you replace "A" with "B", you get your 7th item.

To (5) - the actual question: I can not explain the behavior, but if you use the constant for "wdAutoFitWindow" (which is "2"), the code should work: `WordTable.AutoFitBehavior 2`

Comment: Dear Hoplo, an answer would be nice and, if it is correct, a mark as useful would be highly appreciated.

Comment: thanks, I never came right with the auto-fit - I merely resized the charts and tables in excel until I got the formatting right. I apologize for not replying sooner though. I tried   'wordTable.AutoFitBehavior 2', but no difference I'm afraid.